# What should be in path field of HTTP Authorization manager server health monitoring of Windows server via J meter

Tags: jmeter

As "/manager/status" given for Tomcat server in HTTP Authorization manager. How can we get for  windows   server monitoring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "Windows" stands for ["IIS"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services), I'm afraid you won't be able to use Monitor Results listener.

As per [Building a Monitor Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-monitor-test-plan.html#building) article:

> The monitor was designed to work with the status servlet in Tomcat 5. In theory, any servlet container that supports JMX (Java Management Extension) can port the status servlet to provide the same information.

So for IIS you might want to consider using its own performance counters instead. Check out [How to monitor Web server performance by using counter logs in System Monitor in IIS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/313064) article to get an overall idea on setting this up.

---

If you want a platform-independent and JMeter-integrated solution you can also consider [Servers Performance Monitoring (aka PerfMon)](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) plugin which is absolutely cross-platform and returns much more information than you can get via JMX MBeans. Plugin installation and usage is described in details in the [How to Monitor Your Server Health & Performance During a JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test)